# Parsing the string to original form when string comming through encodeURIComponent in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

I have sent password as a parameter from ajax to one of my WCF service method.

While sending password as it can have "#" in it, I used in javascript as:

```
var encodedPassword = encodeURIComponent(Password);
```

Now it uses %23 ... etc

But when it comes to service method in c# it comes with same form i.e. "%23" in place of "#".

I want to decode it to normal string.

For that i tried :

```
Password = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Password);
```

This thing failed.

```
Password = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Password);
```

This thing failed.

Then how can i decode password to its original form again??? (having # in it)

Comment: In what way does UrlDecode not work. `HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%23")`  returns # for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [UnescapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Password = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(Password);
```

[Dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6YkONW)

Comment: I am sending @# .. string is becoming like : %40%23 when i alert .. and when i do as u suggested it returns only @ ... not returning #

Comment: @CuteChild updated my answer with .netfiddle - all works